# Create new column with multiple values in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, which has name of Stations and Links of Measured value of each Station for 2 days

```
    Station      Link
0   EITZE        https://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/webservices/rest-api/v2/stations/EITZE/W/measurements.json?start=P2D
1   RETHEM       https://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/webservices/rest-api/v2/stations/RETHEM/W/measurements.json?start=P2D
.......
685 BORGFELD     https://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/webservices/rest-api/v2/stations/BORGFELD/W/measurements.json?start=P2D
```

To take data from json isn't a big problem.
But then I realized, that json-link from each station has multiple values from different time, so I don't know how to add these values from each time to a specific station.
I tried to get all the values from json, but I can't define, which values from which station, because it's just too many.
Anyone have a solution for me?
The Dataframe i would like to have, should look like this!

```
        Station     Timestamp                    Value
0       EITZE       2022-07-31T00:30:00+02:00    15
1       EITZE       2022-07-31T00:45:00+02:00    15
.......
100     RETHEM      2022-07-31T00:30:00+02:00    15
101     RETHEM      2022-07-31T00:45:00+02:00    20
.......
xxxx    BORGFELD    2022-08-02T00:32:00+02:00    608
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with this example data frame:

```
  Station                                               Link
0   EITZE  https://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/webservices/res...
1  RETHEM  https://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/webservices/res...
```

You could leverage `apply` to populate an accumulation data frame.

```
import requests
import json
```

**Define the function to be used by apply**

```
def get_link(x):
    global accum_df 
    
    r = requests.get(x['Link'])
    
    if r.status_code == 200:
        ldf = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(r.text))
        ldf['station'] = x['Station']
        accum_df = pd.concat([accum_df,ldf])
    
    else:
        print(r.status_code)    # handle the error
    
    return None
```

**Apply it**

```
accum_df = pd.DataFrame()
df.apply(get_link, axis=1)
print(accum_df)
```

**Result**

```
                     timestamp  value station
0    2022-07-31T02:00:00+02:00  220.0   EITZE
1    2022-07-31T02:15:00+02:00  220.0   EITZE
2    2022-07-31T02:30:00+02:00  220.0   EITZE
3    2022-07-31T02:45:00+02:00  220.0   EITZE
4    2022-07-31T03:00:00+02:00  219.0   EITZE
..                         ...    ...     ...
181  2022-08-02T00:00:00+02:00   23.0  RETHEM
182  2022-08-02T00:15:00+02:00   23.0  RETHEM
183  2022-08-02T00:30:00+02:00   23.0  RETHEM
184  2022-08-02T00:45:00+02:00   23.0  RETHEM
185  2022-08-02T01:00:00+02:00   23.0  RETHEM
```

Comment: Since you're not actually using the return of the function, this is one of the few times where I'd option for doing `for x in df['Link']:` instead of `apply`.

Comment: @BeRT2me Yeah – not afraid of a loop when it makes sense.  For this, I’d have to back all the way off to `iterrows` since I need the `station` ID from the same row.   I’ve been thinking a lot about `apply`-versus-loop since I have used this apply-accumulate-no-return pattern a few times recently.  Is `apply` without a return really a misuse of `apply`?   I’m kind of on the fence on that – though I am a bit uneasy when I do it.  I’ve looked around and haven’t really found any good evidence or opinion one way or another.  Do you have any?  Maybe I ask an SO question to that effect.

Comment: `for x, y in zip(df['Link'], df['Station']):` works as well~

Comment: I just know that I've been looked down on for using list comprehension to do something that should have been a for loop, since you're needlessly creating a list on `None` values, and feel like `apply` is a similar situation, where you're needlessly creating a Series of `NaN` values. On a personal project, I could still see doing it with `apply` like you have for comfort :')

Comment: @BeRT2me Ah, yeah - creating a needless object.  Hadn't thought of that consideration.  I should open myself back up to loops more.  Sometimes they just make sense.  In fact, going back, I am a big-time looper.  Back in the day that's all there was - the only way to handle an array.